# How to disable in app notification counter in whatsapp?

Tags: rooting, root-access, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, 7.1-nougat

Even after muting the chats, WhatsApp still highlights and counts the number of unread messages in an already muted chat. 
[image]

As you can see, there are unread **in app** notifications still there even the chats are muted.

I have a rooted device running Lineage OS 14.1 (Motorola's Moto G4 Plus).

Please don't mark this answer as duplicate, as the other thread's answers are not working for me.

**ShutApp is not working for me (Android 7.1.1). Someone on ShutApp's website pointed that it doesn't work on Marshmallow too.**

This is ShutApp's link:-

https://github.com/eladnava/shutapp-android#usage

Comment: So, those answers are not working for you. Still doesn't deserve another question on the same topic. You can bring the original question to the further attention by upvoting, adding a bounty, editing to include your concerns, etc.

Comment: @wbogacz Okay sorry. Didn't know that.